# Lua replacement for the icomma package?

Tags: luatex, icomma

I thought it would be easy to mimic the `icomma`  package in Lua: my first idea was to add braces around commas in the `process_input_buffer` callback every time a comma is immediately followed by a digit. As pointed out by @UlrikeFisher, this breaks for instance `tikz` commands. As second attempt I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\newcommand*{\luaIC}{\ifmmode\mathord\mathcomma\else,\fi}
\begin{luacode}
  local string_gsub = string.gsub
  function luaicomma (buffer)
  local out = string_gsub (buffer, ",(%d)", "\\luaIC%1" )
return out
end
return luaicomma
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback
               ("process_input_buffer", luaicomma, "intelligent comma")
            }%
}
\begin{document}
0,5 $1,23$ list $(a,b,c)$ interval $[0, 1]$.

\(
  \begin{array}{|D{,}{,}{2}|}
    0,8  \\ 123,45
  \end{array}
\)
\end{document}
```

The problem arises with the `dcolumn` package; the PDF output is correct but I get errors about missing braces in the .log file.

Any hints for a workaround?

Comment: Such as detecting lines containing the string `\begin{array}` and skip processing them? Fickle though.

Comment: I think you will run into more problems if you simply replace every comma with a braced comma, e.g. `\parindent=1,23cm` breaks, or `\tikz\draw(0,1)--(1,1);`, and any command that handle clists as argument, e.g. `\test{1,2,3}`.

Comment: `process_input_buffer` is acting at the wrong level, you want to catch math typeset commas not source commas in argument lists, dcolumn separators, etc. You could use the mlist to hlist callback

Comment: @UlrikeFisher Good point. The second version , -> `\mathord\mathcomma` only in math mode is much less dangerous.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried  the `mlist_to_\hlist` callback, but then the space which must be entered in intervals `[0, 1]` after the comma (the comma must be of class `punct`) has already disappeared.

Comment: @DanielFlipo but you know where you are so could add one, otherwise how are you going to avoid `\put(1,0)` being scrambled as  `\put(1\ifmmode\mathord\mathcomma \else,\fi0)`

Comment: `process_input_buffer` + `string.gsub` is always a recipe for chaos. Lua patterns do respect TeX tokens, so it's basically guaranteed that the input stream will be garbled and TeX chokes.